# Request for CheckBox multiple choice

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

I had a `choice list` I changed it by a `checkbox` for `multiple choice`.
This following my old request MySQL:

```
 $this->_sqlWhere.="`piecearticles`.`ID_Article`=`article`.`ID_Article` 
 AND `article`.`ID_LRU`=`lru`.`ID_LRU` AND `lru`.`LRU`='" . $this->_lru . "'";
```

Since I changed to a multiple choice,should I change it or this one it's fine ?
Thank you.

Comment: The only thing I can tell you about your code from what you have given is that you are almost certainly exploitable by an [SQL injection attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) and should be using something like [prepared statements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement).

Comment: `lru`.`LRU` IN (" . implode(",", $this->_lru) . ")";

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about the answer (because of too little details posted), but this can help: $this->_lru should be an array now.

```
$this->_sqlWhere.="`piecearticles`.`ID_Article`=`article`.`ID_Article`
AND `article`.`ID_LRU`=`lru`.`ID_LRU`
AND `lru`.`LRU` IN (" . implode(",", $this->_lru) . ")";
```